# Unable to verify signature for the data signed in python

Tags: python, java, signature

Below is the code used to sign data using python:

```
# SIGN
rsa_key = get_key(priv_key_file)
signature = sign_file(rsa_key, encrypted)


def sign_file(rsa, byte_buffer):
h = SHA256.new(byte_buffer.getbuffer())
signature = b64encode(pss.new(rsa).sign(h))
return signature
```

In the above code, 'h' refers to generating SHA-256 hash value. And the generated hashvalue i.e. 'h' is signed.

At Java side, I am generating hash value from data which exactly same as generated in Python. But failing to verify the signature.
below is the code used to verify signature in Java:

```
Signature verifier = Signature.getInstance("SHA1WithRSA");
verifier.initVerify(publickey);
verifier.update(signedHash.getBytes());
boolean successFlg = verifier.verify(Base64.getDecoder().decode(signedData));
```

However, if I try using signing and verifying in Java, it is successfully able to verify the signature. Same is the case with signing and verifying in python.

However, only while signed in python and verifying in Java gives signature mismatch.

Please help in the case.

Comment: So in Python you sign it with SHA256 and in Java you verify it with SHA1WithRSA? How could they match if you use different algorithms?

Comment: Security is not my thing, but still, I don't understand, why, in Java code, don't you just do `Signature.getInstance("SHA256");`?

Comment: Tried using : Signature.getInstance("SHA256WithRSA"); still getting same issue.                Trying with Signature.getInstance("SHA256") shows error message as :  SHA256 Signature not available